# Unable to import cancelled type of events in my Calendar from ics file on Outlook Office365 live (WEB)

Tags: outlook, icalendar, outlook-web-app

When I tried to import ics file containing some events it got import successfully to my Outlook calendar. But when I tried to cancel/delete those events on Outlook by importing the ics-cancel file, it gives me the message "Could't import calendar. Try again later.Error message".

[Error thrown on import cancelled ics file on Outlook Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9ECx.png)

**The ICS file containing events :-**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
VERSION:2.0 
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN 
PRODID:-//<Name>//<Name some version> 1.0//EN 
METHOD:PUBLISH 
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:6391ab4dbd29b38442b2d64f 
SUMMARY:Meeting With Max Rob 
DTSTAMP:20221208T072700Z 
DTSTART:20221220T043000Z 
DTEND:20221220T044500Z 
SEQUENCE:0 
DESCRIPTION:Discuss about mid month charts 
LOCATION:<---some link---> 
STATUS:CONFIRMED 
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY 
ATTENDEE;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Max Rob:mailto:<---mail id---> 
ATTENDEE;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Prasun Verma:mailto:<---mail id---> 
END:VEVENT 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:6391ab73bd29b38442b2d661 
SUMMARY:Meeting With Jack Spree 
DTSTAMP:20221208T072700Z 
DTSTART:20221220T093000Z 
DTEND:20221220T094500Z 
SEQUENCE:0 
DESCRIPTION:Get together meet. 
LOCATION:<---some link---> 
STATUS:CONFIRMED 
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY 
ATTENDEE;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Jack Spree:mailto:<---mail id---> 
ATTENDEE;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Prasun Verma:mailto:<---mail id---> 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

**The ICS-cancel file containing cancelled events :-**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
VERSION:2.0 
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN 
PRODID:-//<Name>//<Name some version> 1.0//EN
METHOD:CANCEL 
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:6391ab4dbd29b38442b2d64f 
SUMMARY:Meeting With Max Rob 
DTSTAMP:20221208T072700Z 
DTSTART:20221220T043000Z 
DTEND:20221220T044500Z 
SEQUENCE:1 
STATUS:CANCELLED 
END:VEVENT 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:6391ab73bd29b38442b2d661 
SUMMARY:Calendar Blocked 
DTSTAMP:20221208T072700Z 
DTSTART:20221208T092300Z 
SEQUENCE:1 
STATUS:CANCELLED 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

I need help how to make the events cancelled in the outlook calendar ? Is there a specific format to make events cancelled in outlook? What is the correct way to cancel events so that they disappear in outlook calendar, like in Google Calendar?
This works fine in Outlook Desktop app, I imported the normal ics file, after that I imported cancelled events ics file, I see it did not delete the event rather it stacked it in the same time slot, for example see the 'Meeting with Max Rob' it has been duplicated after importing the cancelled event ics file.
[Importing cancelled event ics after normal ics import on Outlook Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdzdF.png)

When it didn't work on outlook web, I tried importing it in the Outlook Desktop app, it got imported but I saw it stacked the cancelled event.
I expected after importing the cancelled ics file it would disappear the existing imported events from the calendar, like it does on Google calendar.
How do I need to change my ICS, so it works properly?
I saw various threads on stackoverflow, tried but none of them worked for Outlook web.